# Select max visual studio 2010

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, vb6

I'm updating a program from Visual Basic 6 to Visual Studio 2010 and, of course, I have founded a lot of problems so solve.

I'm using Access database with four tables with the same Key (Indice).

If I use the code as follow, I can get the last record from CodDekafix Table:

```vb
Private Sub cmdLast_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles   cmdLast.Click
    Dim Con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\DEKAFIX\Consulta Dekafix\dekafix.mdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
    Con.Open()
    sql = "Select * From Indice Where CodDekafix=(Select max(CodDekafix) From Indice)"
```

But If I want to get all the results from all tables with the same Key (Indice) with the change as showed below the program doesn't work.

```
sql = "Select * from Indice, dekafix1, dekafix2, dekafix3" _
      & " where CodDekafix=(Select max(CodDekafix) From Indice) and" _
      & " Indice.CodDekafix = dekafix1.CodDekafix and" _
      & " dekafix1.CodDekafix=dekafix2.CodDekafix and" _
      & " dekafix2.CodDekafix=dekafix3.CodDekafix and" _
      & " ORDER BY Indice.CodDekafix"
```

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: I think I see the problem, so I've provided an answer below.  But in general, rather than telling us something "doesn't work" and making us guess where you're having trouble, it's better to tell us what error message or exception you're getting and what line it's on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL code in the second code sample is invalid.  When we strip out the formatting representing the string in VB code, you get this:

```
Select * from Indice, dekafix1, dekafix2, dekafix3
where CodDekafix=(Select max(CodDekafix) From Indice) and
Indice.CodDekafix = dekafix1.CodDekafix and
dekafix1.CodDekafix=dekafix2.CodDekafix and
dekafix2.CodDekafix=dekafix3.CodDekafix and
ORDER BY Indice.CodDekafix
```

You have two problems here:

1) There's an extra "and" before the ORDER BY clause.  Remove it.

2) The first line of your WHERE clause has an ambiguous reference to
   `CodDekafix` -- you need to specify what table that's coming from. 
   Replacing `CodDekafix` with `Indice.CodDekafix`should do the trick.

```
sql = "Select * from Indice, dekafix1, dekafix2, dekafix3" _
  & " where Indice.CodDekafix=(Select max(CodDekafix) From Indice) and" _
  & " Indice.CodDekafix = dekafix1.CodDekafix and" _
  & " dekafix1.CodDekafix=dekafix2.CodDekafix and" _
  & " dekafix2.CodDekafix=dekafix3.CodDekafix" _
  & " ORDER BY Indice.CodDekafix"
```

Comment: I removed the exta "and" but the error was the same : "sintax error (operator missing) in query expression "'CodDekafix=(Select max(CodDekafix) From Indice) and Indice.CodDekafix = dekafix1.CodDekafix and dekafix1.CodDekafix=dekafix2.CodDekafix and dekafix2.CodDekafix=dekafix3.CodDekafix and'.

Comment: Based on the error message you've provided, the extra "and" is still in your query.

Comment: But the problem is not finished. Now the error showed is: OleDBException was unhandled - The specified field 'CodDekafix' can refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of the SQL statement.

Comment: Ah, good call.  I've edited my answer to address the issue -- since "CodDekafix" appears in multiple tables that you've joined, you need to pick which one you want to make the comparison to in the WHERE clause.  The first one doesn't have a table name attached to it; specifying "Indice.CodDekafix" should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what do to. I did the same as I did with Visual Basic 5. I need to take the maximum value for CodDekafix from table Indice and get other values from other tables with the same CodDekafix and order by the same data. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @user2319722 - If the extra AND was there all along then how did this ever work in the first place?